# Scheduling job every other day in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, jobs, databricks-workflows

I need to schedule a job which will run every other day(if start is Mon then Wed, Fri, Sunday...).
But in databricks job scheduler options are only for day, week, month and yearly basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron trigger expression consists of 6 fields separated by a space:

0. Seconds (0 -59)
1. minute (0 -59)
2. Hour (0 - 23)
3. Day of the month (1-31)
4. Month (1-12)
5. Day of the week (0-6, 0 = Sunday)
6. Year (optional, default is current year)

For the given schedule, the expression would be:
0 0 0 1/2 * ?

This means that the schedule will run at midnight (0th min and 0th hour) every other day (/2 in the third field). The 4th and 5th fields are not relevant so they are set to a wildcard ().

To summarize, this schedule will run every other day at 12.00 AM

Answer (score 3):

You just need to specify schedule as [cron expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/jobs#--schedule-a-job) instead of using UI options.  Databricks jobs are using [Quartz syntax](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html), so for your case expression will look as following (fill seconds/minutes/hours for time when you need to start jobs):

```
seconds minutes hours * * 1,3,5,7
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following schedule in databricks and it accepts the cron as valid schedule. you can also try the following cron along with @alex-ott's answer.

```
seconds minutes hours ? * 1,3,5,7
```

As you are specifying the `day of the week`, your `day of the month` should be `?`.